# Styling <a> tags and other tags at the same time

Tags: css

I have some css that wasn't written by me and I am trying to understand how to properly edit it.

On my home page http://www.comehike.com I have a list of hikes and groups.  Their titles are wrapped in  tags, but because they have styling for the  tags, the  tags are ignored by the system.

Here is the styling for those spots:

```
.content .chapter_text {
    margin-bottom: 0em; 
    padding: 0.5em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}

.content .chapter_text li{
    list-style-image: url("http://www.comehike.com/img/ui/circle.png");
    margin-left:20px;
}
.content .chapter_text li a{
    color: #7e9940;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.content .chapter_text a:hover{
    color: #3f6b30;
}
```

To make the  tag work, should I just add something like

```
.content .chapter_text h3 
{
What goes here????
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the h3 tag to look like? please clarify.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're asking?

Comment: I guess what the OP wants to know is how to make his H3 look like H3...currently they just look like normal text. See my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should/could add that. That will locate the `h3` tags that have `.chapter_text` and `.content` as parents.

I would think that trying it out yourself would of made a faster answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your reset-min.css has set the following properties for all the headers:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-size: 100%;
font-weight:normal;
}
```

What you want to do as @Phil seconded is to explicitly style the `h3` tags as you pointed out and set the font-size to 120% or something different (or absolute values) and that should solve the problem. I just reset it "on the fly" in chrome's debugger and it seemed to do the trick :)